# How to check an array for carriage return

Tags: c, arrays

I'm just beginning learning C and am working through some basic exercises.  I am writing a small program that asks the user for their name, adds the characters to an array, then prints the array on a screen.  If the user does not enter anything (carriage return), the program should print a message and exit.  It mostly works except that nothing happens when the user just presses enter;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char memberTest[10];
int i;

int main()
        {
        // ASK QUESTION TO BE ANSWERED
        printf("Enter a family member's name (or Press Enter to finish/exit): ");
        //TAKE ENTERED STRING AND INSERT IT INTO FAMILY ARRAY
        scanf("%s", memberTest);
        //IF MEMBERTEST HAS NOTHING IN IT, CLOSE THE PROGRAM
        if(memberTest[0] == '\n')
                {
                printf("You have entered nothing.  Goodbye.\n");
                exit(0);
                }
        //PRINT OUT THE CONTENTS OF THE MEMBERTEST ARRAY
        printf("%s\n", memberTest);
        exit(0);
        }
```

So, the logic in the if statement is that if the first element in the memberTest array is a carriage return ('\n'), it should print the message  and exit (this is on Linux, otherwise I understand that the carriage return for Windows in '\r', I believe).  I'm still trying to understand the proper application for pointers, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This will overflow `memberTest` if the input length is larger than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%s` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace (including newlines) and read the next sequence of non-whitespace characters; it will block until there are non-whitespace characters to read (or it encounters EOF).

You will want to use `fgets` instead.  It will store the newline to the buffer (if there's room left in the buffer):

```
if ( fgets( membertest, sizeof membertest, stdin )
{
  if ( membertest[0] == '\n' )
  {
    // exit
  }
  // process membertest
}
```

For a 10-character buffer, `fgets` will read and store up to 9 characters and write a 0 terminator after the last character. If you type 12 characters, the last 3 plus the newline will not be read from the input stream.  You will want to make sure your buffer is large enough to store your largest expected string plus the newline plus the 0 terminator (or get into dynamic memory management, but you probably don't want to do that yet).

Answer (score 4):

The `'\n'` will not be scanned by `scanf` use `fgets` instead

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char memberTest[10];
int i;

int main()
        {
        // ASK QUESTION TO BE ANSWERED
        printf("Enter a family member's name (or Press Enter to finish/exit): ");
        //TAKE ENTERED STRING AND INSERT IT INTO FAMILY ARRAY
        fgets(memberTest, sizeof memberTest, stdin);
        //IF MEMBERTEST HAS NOTHING IN IT, CLOSE THE PROGRAM
        if(memberTest[0] == '\n')
                {
                printf("You have entered nothing.  Goodbye.\n");
                exit(0);
                }
        //PRINT OUT THE CONTENTS OF THE MEMBERTEST ARRAY
        printf("%s\n", memberTest);
        exit(0);
        }
```

this way you prevent to overflow `memberTest` and read the `'\n'` character.